# Simplifying the expression $\sqrt{(1+\cos t)^2+(-\sin t)^2}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, radicals

I wish to find the length of the parametric curve $$x = f(t) = t + \sin t, y = g(t) = \cos t, t \in [0, \pi]$$

The length $L$ is given by $$\int_0^\pi\sqrt{(f'(t))^2+(g'(t))^2}dt = \int_0^\pi\sqrt{(1+\cos t)^2 + (-\sin t)^2}dt$$

Now, what I *am* able to do with this expression is to simplify it to $$\sqrt{1+2\cos t + \cos^2 t + \sin^2 t}$$ The identity $\sin^2 t + \cos^2 t = 1$ is staring at me, but I do not see how $$\sqrt{2\cos t + 2} = \sqrt{2}\sqrt{\cos t + 1}$$ is going to help me evaluate the integral. Is there another way to simplify the expression so that I'll get an easily computable integral? This task is early in Calc 2, so no very tricky tricks should be needed. I assume I need some expression with [trigonometric identity]-squared so that I will get rid of the square-root, but I honestly don't see how.

Comment: Hint: $\cos 2u=2\cos^2 u-1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the double angle formula,

$$\cos{t} = 2\cos^2\frac{t}{2} - 1$$

So your last line simplifies into $$\sqrt{2\cdot2\cos^2{\frac{t}{2}}}\\=2\left|\cos\frac{t}{2}\right|$$

Comment: I see you deleted your last line about a simpler way to find $L$: was it wrong?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes, the last line was on a simpler way to find the area bounded between the curve $y$ and the $x$ axis, but I mistook L for this area T.T

Comment: Strictly speaking that should be $2\lvert\cos t/2\rvert$. For the limits in the question it doesn't make a difference, but in general it does.

Answer (score 1):

$$
(1+\cos t)^2+(-\sin t)^2=1+2\cos t+\cos^2 t+\sin^2 t=2+2\cos t=4\cos^2\big(\tfrac{t}{2}\big).
$$
Hence
$$
\sqrt{(1+\cos t)^2+(-\sin t)^2}=2\big\lvert\cos\big(\tfrac{t}{2}\big)\big\rvert.
$$